# Admin Page Grid issue

Tags: magento-1.8, grid

I've created my Admin Page Grid but there is a strange issue when I try to prepare the collection.
This is the code:

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
  {
      $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');
      $collection->getSelect()->limit(5,1);
      $this->setCollection($collection);
      return parent::_prepareCollection();
  }
```

and this the result:

[image: the result]

I've try to limit the result to 5 items but it is ignored. The system gets 740 items.
The query generated seems to be right:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_visibility.value = '4') ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
```

I've covered the if the method return $this instead of parent::_prepareCollection(), I obtain the right items but in the Pager area I continue to see "***Total 740 records found***".

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify a function called **_preparePage** in your grid class.

e.g.

```
protected function _preparePage()
{
    $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(5);
    $this->getCollection()->setCurPage(1);
}
```

Note: Its not a complete solution, just an example to show the usage.

Also you have to edit the **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml** file to include the new page size in the grid pagination toolbar. ([See this](http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/adding-rows-per-page-to-magento-admin-grid-and-csv-export-the-simple-way/))

Comment: I've tried to use **setDefaultLimit()** and **setDefaultPage()** methods but they limit the page visibility..
I need to limit the query result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it's impossible to apply limit method to collection. I assume that magento add it's own limitation "view N items per page"

Comment: Yes, it is possible to apply limit method to collection. If my _prepareCollection() function returns **$this** instead of **parent::_prepareCollection()**, I obtain the right number of items.